How to add/display videoclips loop with photoswipe
I wish to use a hugo theme and in there, add some videoclips. The Hugo theme uses photoswipe.
Here is what I try to use. I don't know if I am close or not :
 <a class="gallery-item" data-pswp-video-src="{{ $resource.RelPermalink }}" href="{{ $resource.RelPermalink }}" data-pswp-width="800"
    data-pswp-height="600" title="{{ .Title }}" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/VideoObject" style="aspect-ratio: 8 / 6">
      <figure>
        <video loop muted autoplay playsinline>
          <source src="{{ $resource.RelPermalink }}" type="{{ $resource.MediaType.Type }}" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </figure>
    </a>

I have been trying to use https://github.com/dimsemenov/photoswipe-video-plugin, to add that video support, but I have failed.
What should I do ?

Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not just generally describe your project. See [ask].
